# Problem with Springer Reference style

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I am writing a paper using Springer Nature latex template. I can compile the manuscript with no problems, and the manuscript has been accepted. Now, I was asked to provide date for the entries in the bibliography list, given that in the manuscript there is none.

I am using the numbered vancouver reference style directly from sn-vancouver. Every entry in the .bib file has the data={}; field complete. I am not sure on which supporting file causes the problem: 'sn-jnl.cls' or 'sn-vancouver.bst'. math-phys style does not produce dates either. For example, the following entry in the .bib file gets me the reference which follows

```
@article{binetti_natural_2009,
    title = {The natural transparency and piezoelectric response of the Greta oto butterfly wing},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {1757-9694, 1757-9708},
    url = {https://academic.oup.com/ib/article/1/4/324-329/5211402},
    doi = {10.1039/b820205b},
    pages = {324},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Integrative Biology},
    shortjournal = {Integr. Biol.},
    author = {Binetti, Valerie R. and Schiffman, Jessica D. and Leaffer, Oren D. and Spanier, Jonathan E. and Schauer, Caroline L.},
    urldate = {2023-05-24},
    date = {2009},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Binetti 2009 Greta Oto transparency.pdf:C\:\\Users\\lenovo\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Maestria\\Tesis\\Papers\\Alas mariposa\\Binetti 2009 Greta Oto transparency.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

*Binetti VR, Schiffman JD, Leaffer OD,
Spanier JE, Schauer CL. The natural trans-
parency and piezoelectric response of the
Greta oto butterfly wing;1(4):324. https://
doi.org/10.1039/b820205b.*

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately you've not shown a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964) but only one reference. So I can only guess: Try using `year` instead of `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Thee issue occured because the generated bibligraphy is in Biblatex format, and the template from Springer uses Bibtex. The fields are different, and this caused the error.